# TreeView Selected (active) Node

Tags: asp.net, css

I've got a TreeView with some nodes.

CSS for node:

```
a:link {
    color:#333333;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

CSS for visited node:

```
a:visited {
    color:#333333;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

CSS for selected active mode:

```
a:active {
    color:#222222;
}
```

But it doesn't work for the active element.
Why might that happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the CSS Friendly assembly with your treeview, or is it just a standard .net treeview?  If the latter, checkout SitePoint's examples:

http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?t=591512

You can also check out these examples from OBOUT:

http://www.obout.com/t2/tutorial_css.aspx